# Ionic 2: enter postal -> city selection

Tags: ionic2

I have this code in ionic to ask for the postal and city of the user:

```
 <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-5>
            <ion-item no-padding>
              <ion-input type="number" class="input-without-icon"
                [placeholder]="'reportDetails.contactData.label.postalCode' | translate"
                [(ngModel)]="viewModel.model.contactData.postalCode"
                (ngModelChange)="viewModel.update()"
                [disabled]="viewModel.model.isSubmitted"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-7>
            <ion-item no-padding>
              <ion-input type="text" [placeholder]="'reportDetails.contactData.label.city' | translate"
                [(ngModel)]="viewModel.model.contactData.city"
                (ngModelChange)="viewModel.update()"
                [disabled]="viewModel.model.isSubmitted"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

Now I added a service that returns a list of cities to the given postal. The number of cities can be from 0 to 5.

If the count is 1 the city name should be filled into the city input immediately. If the count is > 1 there should be a select where I can chose between the cities. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngif for this.
*ngIf="cities?.length>0". if length is greater than